# Auto Exposure doesn't work after autoFocus

Tags: android, camera, autofocus

I have **Sony Experia L**, Android 4.2.2.

Camera auto exposure doesn't work after I set autoFocus.

But this properties have value:

```
getExposureCompensation = 0;
getAutoExposureLock = false;
```

How can I fix auto-exposure?
I believe there is way because commercial camera applications working on my phone well.

Thanks.